# Keep getting EADDRINUSE in use errors with Nodemon and Express app using async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, nodemon

This is driving me crazy -- I've tried to make a simple Express app using `async/await` and it works fine, but when it restarts with `nodemon` I keep getting EADDRINUSE errors.  I'm using node version 11.15, this is running under MacOS.

> server up and running on port 4321
>
> events.js:170
>
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4321
>       at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1259:14)
>       at listenInCluster (net.js:1307:12)
>       at Server.listen (net.js:1395:7)
>       at Function.listen (/Users/abc/Documents/Projects/sandbox/axa/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
>       at listen (/Users/abc/Documents/Projects/sandbox/axa/src/server.js:28:15)
>       at tryCatch (/Users/abc/Documents/Projects/sandbox/axa/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
>       at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/abc/Documents/Projects/sandbox/axa/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
>       at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/abc/Documents/Projects/sandbox/axa/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
>       at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/abc/Documents/Projects/sandbox/axa/src/server.js:26:103)
>       at _next (/Users/abc/Documents/Projects/sandbox/axa/src/server.js:28:194)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5) Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at emitErrorNT (net.js:1286:8)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)

I've tried to kill the process in numerous locations -- for example in my `nodemon.json` file I've got `kill-port --port 4321` for `start`, `restart` and `crash`.  My app starts out by killing the port -- from my package.json:

```
"start": " nodemon  --exec 'kill-port --port 4321 & babel-node src/index.js'",
```

And yet, if I type in a file and `nodemon` restarts the app, I get the EADDRINUSE error.  I feel there must be something wrong in my conversion to `async/await`, but I don't know.  My server setup follows -- I get the crash just after `app.listen()`.  What am I doing wrong? Is there something here that is not returning a promise but with which I am using `await`? How can I address the error?  Thanks for any help -- I've spent hours trying to figure this out.

```
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

const {
  env: { DATABASE_URL, PORT, SERVICE_LOAD_INTERVAL = 600000 }
} = process;

const server = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(DATABASE_URL, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    });
    const app = express();
    app.use(cors());
    app.use("/api", routes());
    await setupDB();
    taskSetup(setupDB, SERVICE_LOAD_INTERVAL);
    await app.listen(PORT);
    console.log(`server up and running on port ${PORT}`);
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(`Server Initialisation Error: ${e.message}`);
  }
};
```

My package.json file is

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": " nodemon  --exec 'kill-port --port 4321 & babel-node src/index.js'",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js}\" --quiet",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-handler": "^1.1.4",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "express-jwt-permissions": "^1.3.1",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "kill-port": "^1.5.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.3.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.7.1",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.6.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.1",
    "eslint": "^6.2.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I take it `PORT` in `await app.listen(PORT);` is 4321? also, why are you `await`ing `app.listen` - does it return a Promise? (hint: it does not)

Comment: can you put a `console.log` BEFORE `app.listen` line (after removing superfluous `await`)

Comment: @JaromandaX --  `setupDB` is pulling in data from two remote sites and storing it in a MongoDB -- the code is here https://codepen.io/Cerulean3/pen/ZEzqYBe -- ´taskSetup` is simply to periodically repeat that action.  This is the entire code for that file: `export const taskSetup = (task,time = 60000) => {
   setInterval(task, time)
};`

Comment: @JaromandaX -- and yes, PORT is 4321

Comment: I've removed the comment about setupDB since it's no longer relevant :p

Comment: @JaromandaX -- I removed the await before `app.listen()`, but the problem remains.    The console log is traced fine.  All works well on `yarn start`,  but as soon as I edit a file and nodemon restarts the app, I get the same error: `server up and running on port 4321
events.js:170
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^ Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4321 `

Comment: @JaromandaX -- And the weird thing is that the port has been closed just a moment before!  `[nodemon] starting ``kill-port --port 4321 & babel-node src/index.js`
Process on port 4321 killed``

Comment: it's interesting that `app.listen(PORT);` actually seems to work, and only afterwards you get the `address in use` error - almost like the code is being run more than once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199591/discussion-between-cerulean-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: when you say you've made this using `async-await` - did this work before you made the, as you said, *conversion to async/await*

Comment: can you try `"start": " nodemon  --exec 'kill-port --port 4321 && babel-node src/index.js'"` ... i.e. `&&` not `&` ... because `&` puts the previous command in background, and immediately runs the next command in parallel, whereas, `&&` waits for the previous command to finish before starting the next

Comment: @JaromandaX -- I will try changing the &´s.  I believe the previous version, using promises, did the same thing.  I will go back and investigate though.